# Is there a way to deploy a file using Ansible copy and replace values from parameter store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-parameter-store, aws-ssm

I would like to know if I can use Ansible template/copy and replace multiple values in a file(Ex: .properties,.xml, etc..) while deploying the file to destination with values from Parameter store?

```
Ex-file: app.properties
  app.timeout.value=APP-TIMEOUT-VALUE
  app.zone.value=APP-ZONE-VALUE

Ex-playbook: app.yaml
- name: Deploy app properties
  template:
    src: path/app_name.properties
    dest: /../app_name.properties
  notify:
    - restart app
```

In the above example I want to replace values like(APP-TIMEOUT-VALUE, APP-ZONE-VALUE, etc..) with actual values stored in Parameter Store with Keys as(APP-TIMEOUT-VALUE, APP-ZONE-VALUE, etc..).

Someone please suggest me if there is a straight forward way for it without additional scripts.

Many Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need the ini lookup. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ini_lookup.html

Comment: `APP-TIMEOUT-VALUE` is not a [valid name of Ansible variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names). Fix it if you want to use it in a template.

Comment: I have just added random names as Keys and values just for viewers understanding. I just wanted to show that "app.properties" is a file which has multiple keys and values(SSM Parameter store keys)

Answer (score 0):

Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat app.properties
  app.timeout.value=APP_TIMEOUT_VALUE
  app.zone.value=APP_ZONE_VALUE
```

Create the template

```yaml
shell> cat app.properties.j2
  app.timeout.value={{ APP_TIMEOUT_VALUE }}
  app.zone.value={{ APP_ZONE_VALUE }}
```

If you can't create the template manually the block below would do it for you

```yaml
    - block:
        - copy:
            force: false
            src: app.properties
            dest: app.properties.j2
        - lineinfile:
            backrefs: true
            path: app.properties.j2
            regex: '^(.*)=\s*{{ item }}\s*$'
            line: '\1={{ eval_open }}{{ item }}{{ eval_close }}'
          loop:
            - APP_TIMEOUT_VALUE
            - APP_ZONE_VALUE
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      vars:
        eval_open: "{{ '{{ ' }}"
        eval_close: "{{ ' }}' }}"
```

Customize the paths and loop to your needs

---

Then, use the template. For example

```yaml
    - template:
        src: app.properties.j2
        dest: app_name.properties
      vars:
        APP_TIMEOUT_VALUE: 10
        APP_ZONE_VALUE: 1
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat app_name.properties
  app.timeout.value=10
  app.zone.value=1
```

---

If you can't rename the names of the variables put them into a dictionary. There is no restriction for a key of a dictionary except for being unique. For example

```yaml
shell> cat app.properties.j2
  app.timeout.value={{ app_conf["APP-TIMEOUT-VALUE"] }}
  app.zone.value={{ app_conf["APP-ZONE-VALUE"] }}
```

If you can't create the template manually the block below would do it for you

```yaml
    - block:
        - copy:
            force: false
            src: app.properties
            dest: app.properties.j2
        - lineinfile:
            backrefs: true
            path: app.properties.j2
            regex: '^(.*)=\s*{{ item }}\s*$'
            line: '\1={{ eval_open }}app_conf["{{ item }}"]{{ eval_close }}'
          loop:
            - APP-TIMEOUT-VALUE
            - APP-ZONE-VALUE
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      vars:
        eval_open: "{{ '{{ ' }}"
        eval_close: "{{ ' }}' }}"
```

Then, the template below will give the same result

```yaml
    - template:
        src: app.properties.j2
        dest: app_name.properties
      vars:
        app_conf:
          APP-TIMEOUT-VALUE: 10
          APP-ZONE-VALUE: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Vladimir. But I will not be passing any values to the playbook instead I need to fetch them from AWS SSM Parameter store.